# python not reading the shell environment variable correctly (missing leading "equal" sign)

Tags: python, django, shell, virtualenv, zsh

My shell's (specifically `zsh`) output for a variable is different from Python's `os.environ` output.

I encountered this when I was trying to make a test Django site following what I'm reading in Two Scoops of Django.

I'm trying to put the `SECRET_KEY` value into my `virtualenv`'s `bin/activate` script.

Here's what I placed at the end of `bin/activate`:

```
export SECRET_KEY="=43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z"
```

Doing an `echo $SECRET_KEY` after activating the virtualenv gives:

```
=43v#b7jdiam3#j1s^#ulg=(+ofl=a&^m8-4z
```

as expected. However, when I access that variable in Python using this:

```
import os
print os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
```

it gives me...

```
43v#b7jdiam3#j1s^#ulg=(+ofl=a&^m8-4z
```

(without the leading *equals* sign).

I don't know where the source of the discrepancy is. I don't even know if this is a problem at all but it seems odd that the shell and python reads them differently.

The Django project seems to run alright. Are there going to be problems with this difference in the environment variable?

**Update:**

I have replaced the export line with single quotes. Here are the results:

```
[1] =43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z
[2] 43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z
```

where [1] is the result of `echo $SECRET_KEY` on the terminal while [2] is the result of `import os; print os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]` on the python shell.

**Update 2:**

I'm using Homebrew Python 2.7.6 on Mac OS X 10.8 and Homebrew ZSH 5.0.4.

I continued my investigation and used bash instead of zsh. It worked properly!

Now, is this a problem on `zsh` or in `virtualenv`?

**Update 3:**

I did the `export` line outside of virtualenv using `zsh` and checked the variable again in python. The problem still exists. Therefore, the problem, I think, is with `zsh`.

Comment: Try to escape the dollars and other shell special chars (for example by using `'` as your string delimiter). for me, the initial equals sign is there, but dollars are substituted

Comment: Works for me (with zsh)

Comment: @sk1p I have updated my question with the result of using single quotes instead. The leading "equals" sign is still missing.

Comment: Seems like Python issue. I can't reproduce the problem with Python 2.6.1 on OS X.

Comment: I get the same result when executing anything else than python, I think zsh ( or the one on osx ) is behaving strangely with '='. But I got it correctly if doubling the =. `export SECRET_KEY="==43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z"`. You can verify it's not python by using for instance `perl -e 'print($ENV{SECRET_KEY});'`

Comment: Maybe you are hitting EQUALS-expansion? http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion

Comment: Do you feel a need to get to the bottom of this, or do you just want make sure your project works correctly? If it's the latter you can just change the equals sign to any other character or [generate a new one](http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/) - this is just a random string of characters (note: if you already use the previous key in production this will invalidate all existing sign cookies).

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put single quotes:

```
spaghetti% export SECRET_KEY='=43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z' 
spaghetti% python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os; print os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
=43v#b7jdiam3#j1$02s^#ul$uc$=32g=(+ofl=a&$r_^m8-4z
```

Comment: I have updated my post to use single quotes. Still doesn't work.

Comment: ouch didn't see the update... anyway what version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.7.6 using Homebrew.